# Web Analytics Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, analytics, web

Could you tell me what are the Data Extensions used by Web & Mobile Analytics where i cand find data collected from Javascript in website?
I should retrieve data using firstly a SOAP UI Call, then a SQL query in a child Business Unit of MC Account.

Comment: Thanks i've retrieved data from PI Data Extensions using this API Call [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm]; anyway i cannot retrieve data from PI Data Extension of child business Unit.

Comment: Yes, once you know the DE names (which I've [provided here](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/676dace211b1b2626c4b83ee8dbbe3a7)) then you can retrieve the fields using the API, and once you know the fields, then you should be able to use the DE name and fields in a query.

Comment: In the api call i added this code in order to specify different Business Units
`<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"><RetrieveRequest><Client><ID>XXXXXX</ID></Client><ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS]</ObjectType><Properties>attribName</Properties><Properties>attribValue</Properties></RetrieveRequest></RetrieveRequestMsg>` ; but the response is always the same.